# Every image gets presentational role

Tags: react-testing-library

My tests fail due to images getting "presentation" role. Is it something that's expected? Note: I would like to avoid doing `<img role="img" ... />`.

```js
test('component', () => {
  render(<Component {...defaultProps} />);
  expect(screen.getByRole('img')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with
the role "img"

Here are the accessible roles:

  presentation:

  Name "logo":   

      <img
        alt="logo"
        src="https://google.com/images/logo.png"   
     />
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img - the implicit role for an img element with an empty alt attribute is indeed presentation, so presumably that's what you're doing.

Comment: no, that's not. I'm using an `alt` attr for all my images.

Comment: and also when I'm doing `screen.getByAltText('logo');` it does work too.

Comment: `render(<img alt="logo" src="https://google.com/images/logo.png" />);` then `expect(screen.getByRole("img")).toBeInTheDocument();` works fine for me - presumably you're seeing [this issue](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/1235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in `aria-query@5.2.0`, which you're exposed to transitively via `@testing-library/react`'s dependency on `@testing-library/dom`:

- [A11yance/aria-query#512](https://github.com/A11yance/aria-query/issues/512)
- [testing-library/dom-testing-library#1235](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/1235)

Until an upstream fix is available, `@testing-library/dom@8.20.1` and `@testing-library/dom@9.3.1` pin the dependency to `aria-query@5.1.3`. Either upgrade to those versions or (if you're using NPM 8.3 or above) add:

```json
  "overrides": {
    "aria-query": "5.1.3"
  },
```

to your package file then reinstall.

---

Note that this won't entirely solve image-selecting problems, as the conformance test shared in the above issue fails for either version (albeit for different reasons):

- `aria-query@5.1.3`: `img` elements always have `img` role

  ```
    W3C Recommendations: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance
      ✓ img with no alt has an img role (26 ms)
      ✕ img with an empty alt has a presentation role (2 ms)
      ✓ img with a non-empty alt has an img role (6 ms)
  ```
- `aria-query@5.2.1`: `img` elements with `alt` attributes always have `presentation` role

  ```
    W3C Recommendations: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance
      ✓ img with no alt has an img role (28 ms)
      ✓ img with an empty alt has a presentation role (7 ms)
      ✕ img with a non-empty alt has an img role (1 ms)
  ```

Comment: Thank you, upgrading to `@testing-library/dom@8.20.1` resolved the issue.